# Buttons not aligning with div

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I am trying to make this admin page responsive and there are some problems when I resize the page. I want the div with the Inventory to be aligned with the 3 buttons.

[image]

This is my container which needs to properly adapt when resizing the viewport.

```css
    .reports{
     border: 1px solid red;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     /*overflow-x: hidden; */
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    .row{
     height: 4.5em;
     width: 100%;
     margin-left: 0;
    }
    
    .actions{
     float: right;
     width: 30%;
    }
    .entry-group{
     border: 1px solid red;
     float: left;
     width: 70%;
    }
    
    .title{
     border: 1px solid red;
     float: right;
     width: 72.5%;
     height: 3.7em;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     margin-left: 2em;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="reports">
     <div class="list-group-item row">
      <div class="entry-group">
       <button class="btn btn-primary date" >2016-09-19</button>
              
          <div class="title">
         <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">2080136 - Inventory</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">2 Napier Court West Southend On Sea SS1 1JU</p>
       </div>
      </div>
            
      <div class="actions">
       <button class="btn btn-primary download">Download</button>
       <button class="btn btn-primary edit">Edit</button>
      </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is the screen capture your current or expected output?

Comment: You will need to provide more of your code including CSS and parent elements

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my current output

Comment: @MattStephens 2 seconds and I will add it

Comment: And what is your desired output?

Comment: I want the div that contains the text to go on top, like the date and the two buttons

Comment: @AuroraBrignola can you include some more of the HTML too please. You are also using bootstrap right?

Comment: yes I am, I will try to add more

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Wes good idea Thanks will do so right away

Comment: Completely untested, but have you tried applying `vertical-align: top;` to all of the elements in that row?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1jf7e72v/ I hope this helps

Comment: @DBS I have just tried that and it didn't work :(

Comment: you are using `tr` and `td` tags, but there is no `table` tag...

Comment: In that JS fiddle, you have a margin on top of the `h4` that's pushing it down, add a `margin-top: 0;`, updated copy here: https://jsfiddle.net/1jf7e72v/1/

Comment: @DBS alright, that did work but not completely...because if I make the page even narrower it will push it under the date

Comment: @Johannes thanks for noticing, I have been using a table before and didn't remove them

Comment: @AuroraBrignola do you have media queries setup?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the supplied markup is invalid and should not be expected to work at all.

Comment: If you also add `float: left;` to `.date` and remove the `margin-left: 2em;` from `.title`, it should fix the remaining issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a few issues with the code here. Firstly, I believe it odd to have DIVs between your 'tr' and td', and not having a 'table' element.

I think you are trying to mix different ways of doing things: bootstrap and HTML tables.

My suggestion is use something like layoutit.com to build a layout with divs only in bootstrap. You can easily still integrate it into your back end technology, and get the divs responsive by editing the class names, e.g. col-sm-1.

I understand that you want to use tables for reports, having said that, it should be carried through completely, without divs inbetween.

Comment: It's not odd. It's invalid.

Comment: It doesn't "depend". Invalid markup is invalid markup and this is invalid in every way going back to when the table element was first introduced. Run it through the validator and see the results.

Comment: I am not using tables anymore, that was the first attempt and just didn't remove the tags...sorry for the confusion. I did remove them now but that was not the solution to my problem anyways. Cheers ^_^

Comment: @AuroraBrignola So your markup in your question needs to be changed to what it really is!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.list-group-item-heading {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kefhvc7y/

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
.title h4 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.date {
    float: left;
}
```

and remove `margin-left: 2em;` from `.title`.

Here is an updated version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r11p5n4d/

Comment: @Rob "My" markup is unchanged from the original fiddle. Please feel free to direct any complaints or suggestions their way, I fail to see how copy-pasting this comment to each answer is remotely constructive.

Comment: @Larkeith You are attempting to "fix" markup that is unfixable. That is not being helpful. It's my warning to others that it's a severe problem and should be avoided. You are presenting invalid markup.